# Javascript blinking background colour: when to stop blinking and when to start

Tags: javascript

I've figured out by using the below code, we can blink the background of my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval("Timer()", 500);
var x=1;
var set;
function Timer() 
{
    set=1;
    if(x==0 && set==1) {
        document.bgColor='#00008B';
        x=1;
        set=0;
    }
    if(x==1 && set==1) {
        document.bgColor='#FFFFFF';
        x=0;
        set=0;
    }
}
</script>
```

The html page will forever be blinking with just using this code.
But how do we stop the blinking and start the blinking again?

I want to start blinking when the page received some protocol command, and stop blinking when user press a button on the page. How do we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval returns an ID which can be used to disable the timer. Read the documentation on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var x=1;
var set;

function Timer() 
{
    set=1;
    if(x==0 && set==1) {
        document.bgColor='#00008B';
        x=1;
        set=0;
    }
    if(x==1 && set==1) {
        document.bgColor='#FFFFFF';
        x=0;
        set=0;
    }
}

var timerInterval = null;

startBlinking = function() {
   if(timerInterval === null)
       timerInterval = setInterval(Timer, 500);
}

stopBlinking = function() {
    if(timerInterval !== null) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval)
        timerInterval = null
    }
}
</script>
```

call startBlinking to start the blinking and stopBlinking to stop it. See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/8D3KW/

Comment: is there any initial value for timerInterval?

Comment: initial value will be `undefined`. you can set it to `null` if you want to. I have added a jsfiddle as well. you can check that.

Answer (score 1):

use this http://jsfiddle.net/9FUWu/
you need to do `clearInterval` and use `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `setInterval` to a `var` and then do `clearInterval` on it.

```
var timer = setInterval("Timer()", 500);
...
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: There is an error in the code. You need to pass a string or a function reference to setInterval not a function call which returns undefined. try `setInterval("Timer()",500)` or `setInterval(Timer,500)`

Comment: I have a few buttons on my page. Is there a way to stop blinking by pressing either one of the buttons? How do we detect?

Comment: set the timer as a global variable and use the onclick event of your buttons to access a function that contains the `clearInterval` command

Comment: I have different function for different buttons. Is it that i have to put the stop blinking command on every function?

Comment: yes, or a common function that is called from all onclick functions if you want do do more than just that one command

Answer (score 0):

Save the interval in a variable:

```
var interval = setInterval("Timer()", 500);
```

You can use this variable to clear it later:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```